# Simple web load testing app with GUI

Tags: iis-7, load-testing

I am looking for a simple web load-testing tool that has a GUI.
I need to run lots of small and simple tests (like hit page x 100 time and let me know how long it took).
I do not want to have to script every test as I would have to using WCAT or AB.
Also free would be nice.

If it matters I am using IIS7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found JMeter.

It is very advanced (way more than I need) but it has a nice GUI and has very good docs.

http://jmeter.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of services online that can do this type of testing for you as well. Of course, one of the downsides to this approach is that its harder to correlate the data from the service (which is what can be observed externally) with your own internal data about disk I/O, DB ops, etc. If you end up going this route I would suggest finding a vendor that will give you programmatic access to the raw test result data.